# Windows Server Software RAID 6

Tags: windows-server-2012, software-raid, raid6, storage-spaces

I want to set up a software RAID 6 configuration, but in Windows Server 2008 it only lets me do up to RAID 5.  In Server 2012 I saw they have this new thing called "Storage Spaces" which sounds neat, but I assume you can still set up a basic RAID 5 in 2012.

My question is (and I haven't been able to find a concrete answer): does Server 2012 have support for RAID 6, or, does Storage Spaces somehow do this for you?

Comment: Have you considered a hardware RAID controller?

Comment: This isn't in a professional environment, it's just a personal file server but I thought it was sufficiently complicated to post here.  I could do hardware RAID but the ones that do RAID 6 with 8x+ SATA ports are expensive, and so in my case not ideal (if at all possible).

Comment: @RyanRies Oh yes, I know.  I figured regardless of my situation, the question & answer would end up being more useful here than SuperUser since this is not a common non-professional scenario.

Comment: @RyanRies my 2 cents... you are wrong. First of all superusers is also for powerusers and private data can also be important. At least my personal data is more important for me than any corporate data.

Comment: @Zoredache et al: Also wanted to throw in my 2 cents.  I use Windows software RAID (mostly RAID1) both at home and in some production servers (mostly those with low disk I/O requirements).  Why?  Because Windows arrays are extremely portable.  They can be moved between HP, Dell, and POS SATA controllers, and between Win2K3 through 2012.  It can make a LOT of sense, particularly when cost and mobility are at stake.  Of course, the best (and probably least useful answer in this case) is: Use Linux.  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Server 2012 does not provide software RAID 6 as part of the OS. Your choices with Windows software RAID are still your basic mirroring, striping, or RAID 5 parity.

Storage Spaces in Server 2012 is basically just adding the flexibility to pool different types of cheap storage together, like external USB drives, SATA drives, network storage, etc.

You would need a hardware RAID card capable of doing RAID 6.